# How to stop minted from treating a Bash root prompt ("#") as a comment?

Tags: pdftex, minted, code

`minted` package is treating all Bash root prompts as comments, thus formatting the whole line with a single color and italics (using the default highlighting style). For example:

```tex
\begin{minted}{bash}
# apt-get update
\end{minted}
```

In this case, the `#` isn't a comment, but an `UID 0` (root) prompt.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

I'm compiling the document with:

`latexmk -pdflatex -shell-escape document.tex`

Comment: The prompt is not part of the bash syntax, but the comment is, so the highlighting is correct.  You can mark the `#` as special with `escapeinside`, for example: `\begin{minted}[escapeinside=!!]{bash}
!#! apt-get update
\end{minted}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, that did it. Added the `escapeinside` as a global option with `\setminted{}`.